# HashMap way of doing containsKey not behaving as expected

Tags: java, hashmap, contains

Today I was doing some pathfinding when I had to use `contains()` to find if a class `Coord` was in an other `keySet()` of `Coord`.
I found that when I used to premade method `containsKey()`, it was simply not working as I wanted. I made a test to find out what is happening and here it is:

```
HashMap<Coord, Coord> test = new HashMap<Coord, Coord>();
test.put(new Coord(3, 3), new Coord(0, 0));

System.out.println("HashMap test for containsKey : " + test.containsKey(new Coord(3, 3)));

boolean containsKey = false;
for(Coord a : test.keySet())
{
    if(a.equals(new Coord(3, 3)))
    {
        containsKey = true;
    }
}

System.out.println("My test for containsKey : "+containsKey);
```

And surprisingly, here is what I found :

```
HashMap test for containsKey : false
My test for containsKey : true
```

I just wanted to know what is happening and why.

Also, here is the `Coord` class :

```
public class Coord
{
    public float x, y;

    public Coord(float a, float b)
    {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object b)
    {
        if(b instanceof Coord)
        {
            Coord casted = (Coord) b;
            return casted.x == x && casted.y == y;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all you are checking just `equals()` method. you have not overridden `hashCode()` method. and also you can check the code of `containsKey()` method. it is doing much more thing than you are expecting.you should override `hashCode()` method!!

Comment: Well, i just looked at it and did a third test with a simple test.get(new Coord(3, 3)) != null... And it returned false. I'm looking at the code to understand why.

Comment: better you can check `final Entry<K,V> getEntry(Object key)` method implementation.

Comment: I checked it, and it's almost the same as the  `get` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`HashMap`s find objects by their hash code.  Part of the contract is that the key class must override `hashCode()` as well as `equals()`.  The default hash codes for separate objects aren't equal, so the object isn't found by `get`.  In contrast, when you loop over all entries, the hash code isn't used, so only `equals` is called, and the object is found.

To find it using `get`, override `hashCode` in `Coord`.

It is always good to override `hashCode` whenever you override `equals`, and vice versa.

Answer (score 1):

`Hashmap` actually works on the principal of [**hashing**](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Hashing/hashing.html). For correct & expected results, the key used in the `Hashmap` should override `equals()` as well as `hashCode()`.

So above while you are doing `test.containsKey(new Coord(3, 3))` you are creating a new `Coord` object so its hashcode is different from the `Object` which you have put it the map, as its calling`Object` class `hasCode()` by default. So `containsKey()` giving a `false`

But while you are doing `a.equals(new Coord(3, 3))` you are calling overriden `equals()` which is satisfying the conditions you have put in your overridden method, which is being satisfied by both `Coord` objects, so giving the output as `true`.

For proper results also override `hashCode()` correctly.

For more info on how `HashMap` works in Java, you can see this blog [here](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html). Hope this helped.